# Raspberry Pi. Connection waveshare 10 dof IMU using i2c and python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, i2c

I have connected [waveshare 10dof IMU](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10_DOF_IMU_Sensor_(B)) to my raspberry.

```
sudo i2cdetect -y 1
```

shows me

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 77
```

So, it's good. I have installed **i2c-tools** and **python-smbus**

Next, I try to read data from my IMU. I have written next code:

```
import os
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x68

def pr():
    os.system('clear')
    cnt = 26
    for i in range(1, cnt):
        x = bus.read_byte_data(address, i)
        print x

while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pr()
```

My result is:

```
206
224
222
171
254
233
32
29
211
27
255
0
108
101
125
217
217
231
0
0
0
0
0
```

and it is not changing when I move the IMU.

Please, help me to understand: Why? How to fix it, what is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: For my work I used next Instruction: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-I2C-Python/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: The data is a lot further in the register. You are just reading the setup and config. 0x41 temp_h 0x43 x_h ?gyro
0x45 y_h
0x47 z_h 0x3b x_h ?accel
0x3d y_h
0x3f z_h 0xbb x_h ?Magno
0xbd y_h 0xbf z_h The hex after is the _l (i.e.: 0x42 is temp_l) How to interpret the data... that's something I'm trying to find out myself.